# How do I know if the patent is granted

Tags: pre-grant, patent-applications, us20140114871

How do I know if the below patent is granted?

```
Application Number: 14055444    Application Date:   16.10.2013
Publication Number: 20140114871 Publication Date:   24.04.2014
Publication Kind :  A1  
IPC:    
G06Q 10/10

Applicants: Mobolt, Inc.
Inventors:  Jain Kshitij
Garrett Scott
Priority Data:  
Title:  (EN) RE-ENGINEERING USER LOGIN / REGISTRATION PROCESS FOR JOB APPLICATIONS
Abstract:   
(EN)
An on-line job application process that encourages participants to provide as much information as possible before drop-offs occur, by requesting access to authentication information such as social network identity, and moving an Applicant Tracking System login step to near the end. If a drop off does occur, a dummy email address can then be associated with the user to enable subsequent follow up.
```

I looked at similar questions and I am asked to click on the publication number but it is not a clickable link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [US Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. This gives you lots of detailed information about the status of the application/patent. In this case there was a "Non-Final Rejection" generated on 9-15-2016. This doesn't mean the application won't become a patent as the inventor's attorney can respond in which case the examination will continue.

Comment: Actually thats not correct, an appeal can be used against a final rejection (an RCE is another option). A non final rejection can be answered without other measures beeing necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my answer or you can to make it more correct.

Comment: Public Pair is very useful in this regard.  Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

You google it.

http://www.google.com/patents/US20140114871

There on the right you see that there is no date of grant, so this is still an application. Further information can be retrieved from the links to the USPTO or espacenet. Espacenet also has a family member search:

https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=US&NR=2014114871A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20140424&DB=&locale=

Where you can look up the parent patent application.

Answer (score 0):

Another "quick-and-dirty" way to know if a US patent is granted is by the number format. Granted patents have the following format: US-N,NNN,NNN-B1 or B2. If you see 7 digits followed by a B, it's a patent. If you see more digits and an "A" letter, this refers to the application and you should doublecheck as the fellows already explain above. This is the format used for the past 30 or 40 years, but as indicated below in the comments, it will have to be upgraded soon.

Comment: Well, US 10,000,000 will probably issue some time next year, so 7 digits may not continue on that long...

Comment: A B number is sufficient, but an A number doesn't necessarily mean it's not granted as you could just have the old number, so this is kinda dangerous.

Comment: You are right DonQuiKong, one might just stumble upon the A document and the source of information might at the same time not provide the granted version, if available. I am updating the post.

Comment: And Maca is also right, it will not take that long, I hadn't realized this. Oh dear, it took me almost 6 months to set up a standard procedure of keeping lists of patent families (the US patents/patent applications gave me such a hard time) for my projects. And now I will have to revise this...